buscador php y mysql concatenar
tengo en mi base de datos, registrado un producto que contiene nombre y codigo tengo un buscador que cuando escribo la primera palabra por ejemplo: cartera el resultado son carteras peroooo... si escribo cartera negra me arroja como resultado no existe ese producto y en la base de datos tengo un producto llamado CARTERA BARQ MOD. 009-5 NEGRA (es decir tengo la palabra cartera + negra) y no me muestra resultado si no esta exactamente igual a la descripcion.
Este es mi formulario de busqueda
    <form method="GET" action="buscadorlista.php">

    <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Buscar..." required><br>
    

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto">Buscar Ahora</button>

    </form>

y este es el codigo que recibe al formulario:
<?php

 $query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $conexion->real_escape_string($_GET['query']) : '';

  if ($query) {

 // Consulta SQL
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE activo=1 and nombre LIKE '%$query%' OR codigo LIKE 
'%$query%'";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);

    // Verificar si hay resultados
     if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($data = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

        ?>

no se como concatenar el codigo de busqueda para que me de el resultado.

Sin entrar en el tema de los potenciales problemas de Inyección SQL, lo que tienes que hacer es un subquery LIKE por cada término de la búsqueda, lo ilustro con un ejemplo:
$query = 'cartera negra'; // <-- Ejemplo de valor de búsqueda

$subterms = [];
foreach(explode(' ', $query) as $val) {
    $subterms[] = "nombre LIKE '%$val%'";
}
$subq = implode(' AND ', $subterms);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE activo=1 AND $subq OR codigo LIKE %$query%'";

Si imprimieras la consulta de la variable $sql, será:
SELECT * FROM productos 
WHERE activo=1 
AND nombre LIKE '%cartera%' 
AND nombre LIKE '%negra%' 
OR codigo LIKE '%cartera negra%'

